# Extracting a function from a list

Tags: r, tibble

I'm having trouble pulling a function out of a list of functions. and have to use the [[1]] operator. see below:

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

fns = tibble(fn_name = c('plus', 'multiply'),
             fn = list(function(x,y) x + y,
                       function(x,y) x * y))


my_x = 2
my_y = 3
my_fn_name = 'plus'

my_fn = fns %>% 
  filter(fn_name == my_fn_name) %>% 
  pull(fn)

my_fn[[1]](my_x, my_y)
#> [1] 5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is there a more elegant way to do this, without having to call `my_fn[[1]]`? I don't think functions are allowed to be vectors, which is why I can't treat it like I would if I applied `pull` to a vector of atomics.

Comment: You can `pluck`.  Not sure how you define elegance.  Should that be in a single pipe i.e. `fns %>% filter(fn_name == my_fn_name) %>% transmute(out = pluck(fn, 1)(my_x, my_y))`

Comment: Do you really need your functions to be in a tibble? That certainly makes things more difficult. A list would be easier: `fns = list(plus = function(x,y) x + y, multiply = function(x,y) x * y)` You can then access elements with names or indexes. So `fns[[my_fn_name]](my_y, my_y)`, No need for `filter()`

Comment: thanks @MrFlick. Definitely the right solution for my use case. However in cases where storing metadata about functions is important, a data frame would be required.

Comment: I’m still not sure that’s true. You can add metadata to a list via attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```r
fns %>% 
  filter(fn_name == my_fn_name) %>% 
  unlist() %>%
  purrr::pluck("fn")

#> function(x,y) x + y
#> <environment: 0x000001cfdcd6d4f8>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the addition of `purrr`, you can do:

```
fns %>%
 filter(fn_name == my_fn_name) %>% 
 pull("fn") %>%
 map_dbl(exec, !!!list(my_x, my_y))

[1] 5
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also do

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
fns %>%
     filter(fn_name == my_fn_name) %>% 
     transmute(out = pluck(fn, 1)(my_x, my_y)) %>%
     pull(out)
#[1] 5
```